Getting error and don't know how to solve it - Object has no field all
closelong = (n1 < n2 and p < n2 and confidence < dt) or (strategy.opentrades.profit(strategy.opentrades.size(strategy.opentrades.all)) < SL) or (strategy.opentrades.profit(strategy.opentrades.size(strategy.opentrades.all)) > TP)

I dont know how to solve it. Many Thanks!
i want that total number is all but 'strategy.opentrades.all' is wrong.

Well, you cannot just type something and expect it to exist.
If you want to figure out the open profit of all the open trades, then you need to loop through each open trade:
// Calculate open profit or loss for the open positions.
tradeOpenPL() =>
    sumProfit = 0.0
    for tradeNo = 0 to strategy.opentrades - 1
        sumProfit += strategy.opentrades.profit(tradeNo)
    result = sumProfit

